# Inheriting Object's methods such as keys() in an interface

Tags: typescript

I want to use a Javascript Object as a hashmap type. The documented way to do is with the following syntax:

```
interface MyHashMap {
  [name:string]: string;
}
```

But I'd love to be able to access Object methods such as keys(), for example
to do the following:

```
let m : MyHashMap = { foo: "why", bar: "not" }
console.log(m.keys().sort())
```

But that doesn't work:

```
$ tsc src/testsort.ts 
src/testsort.ts(6,15): error TS2339: Property 'keys' does not exist on type 'MyHashMap'.
```

This however works:

```
console.log(Object.keys(m).sort())
```

But that's clearly unnecessarily verbose, and doesn't reflect the fact that 
MyHashMap is actuall an Object, and that I want it to be treated as such. Is
there a way to express this?

Additionally, is there a straightforward way to have generics over Object, and 
not just Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you want to use the **keys** static method of the class **Object** as a regular method of all instances of the class **Object**.

First of all, as far as I know, you can't describe static methods in interfaces (because interfaces are used for instances, not for classes).

But there might be a workaround:

1. You need to declare an interface for **Object** instances.
2. You need to extend the regular **Object** class and add there the **keys** method for instances.

Secondly, you want to use the method **keys** for the interface **MyHashMap**. It means, that you have to extend the interface **MyHashMap** (by the way, I would advice to call it **IMyHashMap** or something like that with big I at the beginning) from the interface **Object**. But it would lead to the many compiler errors, because the index-based syntax where we use **string** as index means, that every property/method should return the same type (in your case **string**). But there is a warkaround too: I would advice to use union types for the variable **m**.

Please, check the code below and pay attention to the comments:

```
// Declare an interface for the Object and declare a method for it
interface Object
{
    keys(): string[];
}

// Implement the declared method keys (otherwise the method keys would "exist" only in typescript,
// there wouldn't be any code for this method in JS)
Object.prototype.keys = function (): string[]
{
    return Object.keys(this);
}

// Declare an interface for the custom hash-map objects
// (please, pay attention that this interface uses generic type)
interface MyHashMap<ItemType>
{
    [name: string]: ItemType;
}

// Create a variable of Union-Type (it's an instance of MyHashMap<string> and of Object at the same time)
let m: MyHashMap<string> | Object = { foo: "why", bar: "not" };
console.log(m.keys().sort());
```

Comment: Ah ok I understand I was confused, I thought that keys() was in Object.prototype, but in fact it's only in Object itself. Therefore Object.keys(m) is the proper way to do it anyway. Thanks.